# Is the language regular A2 = {w1w2w3 | w1, w2, w3 ϵ {0, 1}* }? How to prove?

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, automata, regular-expressions, pumping-lemma

So I think the above language is regular. I tried using pumping lemma but pumping up or down, changes the value of w1 but has no relation with *w2* or *w3*. The resulting string after pumping will also be in the language. I think the language *w1w2w3* is just similar to {0,1}* . I can create a NFA for {0,1}* , so that is why the language is regular. *w1w2w3* is just like a concatenation of *w1,w2,w3* but all of them are {0,1}* so the NFA for the language {0,1}* is also the NFA that accepts the language A2. Is my thinking so far correct? Will the NFA accept the language?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

1. If you think the language is regular, there is no point using the pumping lemma. It is used to prove that some languages are NOT regular.
2. The sentence "$\{0,1\}^*$ can represent the NFA for the language" makes absolutely no sense.
3. Your language is equal to $\{0,1\}^*$ (you can choose any $w_1$, and $w_2 = w_3 = \varepsilon$).

Comment: Thank you for the reply. For 2) I wanted to say the NFA that represents the {0,1}* not the other way around, I edited it. So, since per 3) the language A2 is equal to the language {0,1}*, the above NFA accepts the language A2. Am I right in saying that since w1,w2,w3 all belong to {0,1}*, then the resulting string w1w2w3 also is in {0,1}*?

Comment: Also, I was not sure for 1), I tried pumping lemma to verify if I can prove it not regular but I could not find a string to do so. I guess where I am confused is: you say choose *w1* and *w2 = w3 = ε*, then language is equal to {0,1}*, but say for an irregular language *w1w2w1*, can't I do the same and get the result language is equal to {0,1}*? But that is not true. So I am making a mistake somewhere (in choosing the values of *w1,w2*).

Comment: For your first comment: there were no NFA in your initial post. In your edit, this is in fact a DFA, and it does not have an initial state, so it recognizes the empty language. For your second comment: you cannot do the same thing with $\{w_1w_2w_2\mid w_1, w_2\in \{0,1\}^*\}$, because if you choose $w_1$ to be any non-empty word, you cannot choose it to be the empty word at the same time.

Comment: Thanks @Nathaniel